# Zkoss Spring Security always returns AnonymousAuthenticationToken

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security, zk

I have a question due to Spring-Security and Zkoss. My current problem is that Spring authenticates my current user always as an anonymous user altough I correctly logged in as admin (alias: admin, pw: admin). I created my own AuthenticationProvider which verifies the correct login data. This is my security context xml file:

```
    <http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/login.zul" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/index.html" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />
    <logout logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" logout-success-url="/logout.zul" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="accessDeniedHandler" />

    <!-- <custom-filter position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" ref="concurrencyFilter" /> -->
    <!-- <session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas" /> -->
</http>

<beans:bean id="httpSessionSecurityContextRepository" class="com.tembit.terminator.security.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository" />

<beans:bean id="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <beans:property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login.zul" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="accessDeniedHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl">
    <beans:property name="errorPage" value="/error.zul" />
</beans:bean>

<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

<beans:bean id="usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/j_security_check" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <beans:property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" ref="sas" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler">
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
            <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/index.html" />
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="authenticationFailureHandler">
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
            <beans:property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/error.zul" />
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="sas" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
    <beans:property name="maximumSessions" value="1" />
    <beans:property name="exceptionIfMaximumExceeded" value="true" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="concurrencyFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter">
    <beans:property name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
    <beans:property name="expiredUrl" value="/index.html" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="sessionRegistry" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />

<beans:bean id="authenticationProvider" class="com.tembit.terminator.auth.AuthentificationProvider" />

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider ref="authenticationProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>
```

And this is my AuthenticationProvider

```
@Service
```

public class AuthentificationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

```
@Autowired
private UserManager userManager;

@Override
public Authentication authenticate(final Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    final User user = userManager.findByAlias(authentication.getPrincipal().toString());

    if (user.getId() == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid credentials");
    }

    final HashUtil util = new HashUtil();
    final String suppliedPassword = util.hash(authentication.getCredentials().toString());
    if (!user.getPassword().equals(suppliedPassword)) {
        throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid credentials");
    }

    return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, user.getAuthorities());
}

@Override
public boolean supports(final Class<?> authentication) {
    return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
}
```

}

This is my user class

```
public class User implements BaseEntity, UserDetails {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(length = 50, nullable = false, unique = true)
private String alias;

@Column(columnDefinition = "text")
private String password;

@Version
private Long versionCount;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "UserRole", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "userId") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "roleId") })
private Set<Role> roles;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    final Set<Authority> authorities = new HashSet<Authority>();
    for (final Role role : roles) {
        for (final Permission permission : role.getPermissions()) {
            final Authority authority = new Authority(permission.getName());
            authorities.add(authority);
        }
    }
    return authorities;
}

public void setPassword(final String password) {
    final HashUtil util = new HashUtil();
    this.password = util.hash(password);
}

@Override
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setUsername(final String username) {
    alias = username;
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {
    return alias;
}

public Set<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}

public void setRoles(final Set<Role> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = (prime * result) + ((alias == null) ? 0 : alias.hashCode());
    result = (prime * result) + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
    result = (prime * result) + ((password == null) ? 0 : password.hashCode());
    result = (prime * result) + ((roles == null) ? 0 : roles.hashCode());
    result = (prime * result) + ((versionCount == null) ? 0 : versionCount.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final User other = (User) obj;
    if (alias == null) {
        if (other.alias != null) {
            return false;
        }
    } else if (!alias.equals(other.alias)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (id == null) {
        if (other.id != null) {
            return false;
        }
    } else if (!id.equals(other.id)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (password == null) {
        if (other.password != null) {
            return false;
        }
    } else if (!password.equals(other.password)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (roles == null) {
        if (other.roles != null) {
            return false;
        }
    } else if (!roles.equals(other.roles)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (versionCount == null) {
        if (other.versionCount != null) {
            return false;
        }
    } else if (!versionCount.equals(other.versionCount)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "User [id=" + id + ", alias=" + alias + ", password=" + password + ", versionCount=" + versionCount + ", roles=" + roles + "]";
}

@Override
public Map<String, Object> getPatternMap() {
    final Map<String, Object> patternMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    if (alias != null) {
        patternMap.put("alias", alias);
    }
    return patternMap;
}
```

}

This are the Roles

```
public class Role implements BaseEntity, Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(length = 50, nullable = false, unique = true)
private String name;

@Column(columnDefinition = "Text")
private String description;

@Version
private Long versionCount;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "PermissionRole", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(table = "Role", name = "roleId") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(table = "Permission", name = "permissionId") })
private Set<Permission> permissions;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "UserRole", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "roleId") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "userId") })
private Set<User> users;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(final Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(final String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(final String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public void setPermissions(final Set<Permission> permissions) {
    this.permissions = permissions;
}

public Set<Permission> getPermissions() {
    return permissions;
}

public Set<User> getUsers() {
    return users;
}

public void setUsers(final Set<User> users) {
    this.users = users;
}

public Long getVersionCount() {
    return versionCount;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = (prime * result) + ((description == null) ? 0 : description.hashCode());
    result = (prime * result) + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
    result = (prime * result) + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
    result = (prime * result) + ((permissions == null) ? 0 : permissions.hashCode());
    result = (prime * result) + ((versionCount == null) ? 0 : versionCount.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final Role other = (Role) obj;
    if (description == null) {
        if (other.description != null) {
            return false;
        }
    } else if (!description.equals(other.description)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (id == null) {
        if (other.id != null) {
            return false;
        }
    } else if (!id.equals(other.id)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (name == null) {
        if (other.name != null) {
            return false;
        }
    } else if (!name.equals(other.name)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (permissions == null) {
        if (other.permissions != null) {
            return false;
        }
    } else if (!permissions.equals(other.permissions)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (versionCount == null) {
        if (other.versionCount != null) {
            return false;
        }
    } else if (!versionCount.equals(other.versionCount)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Role [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", description=" + description + ", versionCount=" + versionCount + ", permissions=" + permissions + "]";
}

@Override
public Map<String, Object> getPatternMap() {
    final Map<String, Object> patternMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    if (name != null) {
        patternMap.put("name", name);
    }
    if (description != null) {
        patternMap.put("description", description);
    }
    return patternMap;
}
```

}

This is the login page

```
<?variable-resolver class="org.zkoss.zkplus.spring.DelegatingVariableResolver"?>
```

```
    <hbox id="errorMessageHbox" align="center" visible="false">
        <label id="errorMessage"/>
    </hbox>

    <h:form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" method="POST" action="j_security_check" xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" autocomplete="off">

        <grid>
            <columns>
                <column width="100px"/>
                <column width="300px"/>
            </columns>
            <rows>
                <row align="right">
                    <label value="${c:l('login.zul.lbUserName')}"/>
                    <textbox id="tbUsername" readonly="false" width="100%" maxlength="50" value="admin" />
                </row>
                <row align="right">
                    <label value="${c:l('login.zul.lbPassword')}"/>
                    <textbox id="tbPassword" type="password" width="100%" maxlength="50" value="admin" />
                </row>
                <row align="right">
                    <cell colspan="2" align="right">
                        <button id="btnLogin" sclass="primaryButton" label="${c:l('login.zul.btnLogin')}"/>
                    </cell>
                </row>
            </rows>
        </grid>

        <!-- Unvisible fields -->
        <textbox id="j_username" name="j_username" visible="false"/>
        <textbox id="j_password" name="j_password" visible="false" type="password"/>
    </h:form>
</window>
```

and this is the loginComposer

```
public class LoginComposer extends BasePageComposer<Component, User> {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

// security form fields
protected Textbox j_username;
protected Textbox j_password;

protected Form loginForm;
protected Textbox tbUsername;
protected Textbox tbPassword;

public void onClick$btnLogin() {
    submitLoginForm();
}

protected void submitLoginForm() {
    if ((tbPassword.getValue() != null) && !tbPassword.getValue().isEmpty()) {
        if ((tbUsername.getValue() != null) && !tbUsername.getValue().isEmpty()) {
            j_password.setValue(tbPassword.getValue());
            j_username.setValue(tbUsername.getValue());
        } else {
            throw new WrongValueException(tbUsername, ComposerUtil.getLabel("login.zul.validation.emptyUserName"));
        }
    } else {
        throw new WrongValueException(tbPassword, ComposerUtil.getLabel("login.zul.validation.emptyPassword"));
    }

    try {
        session.setAttribute("loginPerformed", true);
        Clients.submitForm(loginForm);
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}

@Override
protected String getPageTitle() {
    return ComposerUtil.getLabel("login.zul.pageTitle");
}
```

}

Whenever I authenticate correctly with the admin user (and an UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken is returned in the AuthentificationProvider) it will be replaced by an AnonymousAuthenticationToken after processing the AnonymousAuthenticationFilter. How can I prevent the Filter from creating the AnoynmousToken?

Could you please help me? If you need more informations, I will hand them.

Best wishes, Anyone

Answer (score 0):

For those who have the same problem: The problem was zkoss comet server push which modified the authentication process. The session was somehow added to the thread of the zkoss comet server instead of the authentication requests thread. Very strange.

The soloution: Disable the zkoss comet server!

Best wishes, Anyone